# Cannot resolve method 'forEach(<lambda expression>)' in Android Studio

Tags: java-8, android-studio-2.3

I have just added Java 8 support to my app with

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

and

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

I have this code:

```
for (Company company : companies) {
    save(company);
}
```

and Android Studio tells me that it

> Can be replaced with foreach call

After replace it, it looks like this:

```
companies.forEach((Company company) -> {
    save(company);
});
```

But now it's complaning:

> Cannot resolve method 'forEach()'

I can compile and run my app properly. It's all about the editor.

Any idea? I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: Did you set a minSdkVersion >= 24? `forEach` is a default method in Java.lang.Iterable introduced in Java 8. It's onyl available for min SDK >= 24.

Comment: Yup, it is. You can't use Java8 *API* methods (as opposed to Java 8 *language features*) below 24.